# Find the smallest positive integer $k$, such that product of $420$ and $k$ is a perfect square.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the smallest positive integer $k$, such that product of $420$ and $k$ is a perfect square.

Please help me in this question.

Answer (score 5):

What you *really* need is not an answer to the specific question but an understanding of the general principle you need to be deploying here. So let's think about the general problem: Given $n$ find the smallest $k$ such that $m = n \cdot k$ is a perfect square. What to do?

Good hint for questions such as this: *think about factorization* (as the question, *is $m$ a perfect square* is a question about how it factorizes). So ...

What are the properties of the factors of perfect squares $m$? Well since $m = j^2$ any factor of $j$ must occur twice in $m$. So any prime factor of $m$ must occur an even number of times.

And that gives us our clue to how to proceed:

> Step one. Factorize $n$.
>
> Step two. Look to see which primes *don't* appear an even number of times in the factorization.
>
> Step three. Take $k$ to be the product of those primes with an odd number of occurrences in $n$.

So -- by brute force construction -- $n \cdot k$ is the product of primes, each one of which now occurs an even number of times as we want. So $m = n \cdot k$ is a perfect square. And we've put into $k$ the fewest prime factors needed to make the product with $n$ a perfect square. So we are done.

Now you have the principle of the thing, you should be able to see how to do *this* problem too: *Find the smallest number $k$ such that $420 \cdot k$ is a perfect cube* and other problems in the same family.

Answer (score 3):

$420=2^2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7$

Observe that the power of $3,5$ and $7$ in $420$ is $1$

So, to make the power of $3$ even, we need to multiply $420$ by $3^{2a+1}$ where $a$ is a non-negative integer.

So, the general value of $k$ is $3^{2a+1}\cdot5^{2b+1}\cdot7^{2c+1}$ where $a,b,c$ are non-negative integers.

So, the smallest positive integer value of   $k$ is $3\cdot5\cdot7=105$ (putting $a=b=c=0$)

Observe that $\frac{420}{105}=4=2^2$ is also a perfect square.

If $A\cdot B$ is perfect square, so will be $\frac AB$ if $B\mid A$